Movie where group of strangers is stuck in a cabin
I'm looking for a movie. Here's what I remember:

At the start of the movie, a couples' car breaks down.  The husband goes out to search for help.
The wife suddenly wakes up in an empty cabin.  She eventually meets several other people.  They discover that when they leave the cabin and walk through the woods in a straight line, they end up back at the cabin.
One of the characters is a soldier who believes there is a hunter in the woods trying to kill him.
One of the characters is a rebellious girl whose mother abandoned her when she was young.
The characters eventually find out


 They are all related but from different time-periods.  The solider is the great-grandfather who went missing during WWI, the wife is the mother of the girl whose mother abandoned her.

In the end the hunter tries to kill them but


 the girl gives her life to save the mother.  The mother is able to go back to her time-period, and doesn't abandon the girl this time.

I watched it online a few years ago.  I think on Netflix?  It didn't seem very old at the time.
I think it was an indie movie because the acting was horrible, despite having such a good story.

